# Draw skier with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a skier with the tikz package. I made the drawing below, but I am not satisfied. I am looking to bring improvements to my drawing and I ask if someone can help me or guide me.

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[manstyle/.style={line width=4pt,line 
cap=round,line join=round},line cap=round,line join=round]   
%\draw[step=2mm,help lines] (0,0) grid (100mm,50mm);03   
\draw[step=10mm] (0,0) grid (100mm,50mm);

\draw [ultra thick] (2,0) to[out=0,in=180] (4,0) to[out=0,in=0] (4.2,0.2);

\node[fill,circle,inner sep=4pt,outer sep=2pt] (head) at (3.53cm,2.36cm) {}; 

\draw[line width=10pt] (2.8,1.2) -- ++(.5,.8cm);
\draw[manstyle] (3.1,0.04) -- ++(.48,.8cm);
\draw[line width=6pt] (3.55,0.86) -- ++(-.8,.285cm);
\draw[line width=4pt] (3.3,2.1) -- ++(.5,-.7cm);
\draw[line width=2pt] (3.8,1.4) -- (2.6,.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

i want something like that :

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you don't like in your skier? Looks good for me.

Comment: I like make it more realistic and prettier. Is there a package to draw things like that.

Comment: Can you add a freehand drawing of the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is awesome:

[image]

1. Open original with inkscape.
2. Select image, then select Path -> Trace bitmap.
3. Select one method, I am using "Brightness Steps".
4. Click update to see results, then press OK to trace bitmap.
5. Delete origin bitmap, keep the generated one.
6. Resize page size to fit content. (File->Document Properties->Resize to drawing or selection.
7. Export to .tex file from File->Save As e.g. drawing.tex.

Now use this wrapper.tex to include .tex file:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{drawing.tex}
\end{document}

xelatex wrapper.tex
```

drawing.tex:

```
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(587.42588073,344.85191886)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(11.476375,1.26222386)
\curveto(4.040424,2.49918386)(0,4.27725386)(0,6.31264386)
\curveto(0,7.26050386)(5.783671,7.49012386)(19.0625,7.06942386)
\curveto(36.521509,6.51628386)(40.280512,6.82295386)(63.749996,10.71513386)
\curveto(124.826446,20.84404386)(183.690446,32.25317386)(211.874996,39.42498386)
\curveto(221.499996,41.87414386)(230.686836,44.17425386)(232.290186,44.53634386)
\curveto(235.084346,45.16735386)(237.248446,48.03219386)(235.928236,49.35240386)
\curveto(235.581416,49.69924386)(229.671736,48.55692386)(222.795646,46.81393386)
\curveto(204.821646,42.25775386)(163.023426,33.15767386)(136.874996,28.10775386)
\curveto(101.436946,21.26377386)(80.857296,18.46628386)(60.507796,17.72680386)
\curveto(41.00665,17.01815386)(34.38087,17.96652386)(31.084674,21.93818386)
\curveto(28.160475,25.46163386)(32.702135,26.97165386)(48.442006,27.70920386)
\curveto(74.149246,28.91382386)(222.796496,54.97717386)(246.874996,62.50183386)
\curveto(254.962426,65.02919386)(256.199296,65.90839386)(263.209186,74.11262386)
\curveto(267.380486,78.99462386)(273.101426,84.67648386)(275.922386,86.73898386)
\curveto(280.010416,89.72788386)(281.220626,91.52328386)(281.885176,95.58501386)
\curveto(282.645896,100.23464386)(282.218476,101.39694386)(277.005346,108.85437386)
\curveto(264.772076,126.35423386)(257.499996,138.99916386)(257.499996,142.77091386)
\curveto(257.499996,145.23477386)(254.442136,151.60755386)(248.697776,161.11531386)
\curveto(238.928916,177.28422386)(233.824546,188.59743386)(233.779676,194.17947386)
\curveto(233.759776,196.65622386)(235.051216,199.21248386)(237.706446,201.95198386)
\curveto(240.622986,204.96108386)(241.197946,206.19247386)(239.893946,206.63692386)
\curveto(238.921026,206.96853386)(232.703416,209.23653386)(226.077036,211.67692386)
\curveto(219.450666,214.11731386)(213.209716,216.11398386)(212.208276,216.11398386)
\curveto(211.206826,216.11398386)(209.315916,217.31662386)(208.006236,218.78651386)
\curveto(204.745666,222.44593386)(198.579726,224.86398386)(192.508926,224.86398386)
\curveto(180.896916,224.86398386)(166.062246,233.33179386)(164.639976,240.77192386)
\curveto(163.661686,245.88948386)(166.230966,252.67584386)(170.765996,256.95293386)
\curveto(173.094696,259.14917386)(174.999996,261.45919386)(174.999996,262.08630386)
\curveto(174.999996,264.20827386)(179.554026,267.36405386)(182.598426,267.35177386)
\curveto(184.263036,267.34577386)(188.496546,266.00248386)(192.006226,264.36827386)
\curveto(195.515886,262.73406386)(203.186726,260.75830386)(209.052526,259.97770386)
\curveto(214.918326,259.19712386)(222.342886,257.66393386)(225.551566,256.57063386)
\curveto(228.760226,255.47733386)(231.620416,254.81773386)(231.907536,255.10485386)
\curveto(232.194666,255.39198386)(230.396696,258.64557386)(227.912066,262.33506386)
\curveto(225.207916,266.35048386)(223.163376,271.08954386)(222.818676,274.14109386)
\lineto(222.242836,279.23898386)
\lineto(215.925716,279.18138386)
\curveto(210.085096,279.12818386)(209.267186,278.72742386)(205.082716,273.86888386)
\curveto(200.132766,268.12157386)(196.868026,267.19752386)(195.602276,271.18555386)
\curveto(195.153366,272.59993386)(193.427966,274.27351386)(191.768036,274.90461386)
\curveto(190.108116,275.53577386)(188.749996,276.62856386)(188.749996,277.33307386)
\curveto(188.749996,278.03759386)(187.906246,278.61401386)(186.874996,278.61401386)
\curveto(185.843746,278.61401386)(184.999996,279.46441386)(184.999996,280.50379386)
\curveto(184.999996,282.00844386)(183.981046,282.23062386)(179.999996,281.59402386)
\curveto(175.309116,280.84392386)(174.999996,280.98391386)(174.999996,283.85842386)
\curveto(174.999996,285.87496386)(172.714126,289.26364386)(168.313086,293.77134386)
\curveto(161.640946,300.60519386)(161.625646,300.63915386)(161.391826,309.13817386)
\curveto(160.757876,332.18194386)(172.128696,344.82322386)(193.516186,344.85180386)
\curveto(200.890166,344.86180386)(203.967726,344.22240386)(209.435416,341.54514386)
\curveto(213.163336,339.71975386)(217.170026,337.16925386)(218.339166,335.87736386)
\curveto(220.401996,333.59796386)(220.510446,333.63141386)(222.005916,337.00875386)
\lineto(223.546946,340.48901386)
\lineto(223.686486,336.11401386)
\curveto(223.801366,332.51375386)(224.051636,332.12637386)(225.100126,333.92651386)
\curveto(227.152136,337.44960386)(228.753546,336.44426386)(227.898626,332.16965386)
\curveto(227.334686,329.34996386)(227.521816,328.47995386)(228.554876,329.11842386)
\curveto(230.367966,330.23896386)(230.392076,329.18232386)(228.628576,325.88721386)
\curveto(227.874326,324.47786386)(227.733696,323.53046386)(228.316076,323.78188386)
\curveto(228.898466,324.03330386)(233.031216,326.06286386)(237.499966,328.29201386)
\curveto(262.978016,341.00124386)(294.442176,334.53399386)(332.636976,308.73725386)
\curveto(350.259596,296.83495386)(362.479696,286.40514386)(370.949186,276.03792386)
\curveto(374.846566,271.26727386)(378.826576,267.36401386)(379.793646,267.36401386)
\curveto(380.760736,267.36401386)(412.966676,270.45776386)(451.362396,274.23901386)
\curveto(489.758136,278.02026386)(522.033926,281.11401386)(523.086386,281.11401386)
\curveto(526.098576,281.11401386)(525.319276,278.96517386)(522.005446,278.13346386)
\curveto(518.941116,277.36436386)(426.398336,267.44276386)(396.562466,264.68460386)
\curveto(387.453086,263.84249386)(380.008576,262.83522386)(380.019096,262.44625386)
\curveto(380.117796,258.80010386)(383.190626,258.91945386)(443.768496,264.92236386)
\curveto(477.789546,268.29365386)(508.409336,271.06592386)(511.812466,271.08298386)
\curveto(521.295866,271.13048386)(517.199016,268.94713386)(504.999966,267.45228386)
\curveto(492.312366,265.89757386)(386.640626,254.86401386)(384.438276,254.86401386)
\curveto(383.405196,254.86401386)(382.880316,252.43984386)(382.833326,247.45170386)
\curveto(382.711326,234.49689386)(372.388246,216.66545386)(360.421696,208.73912386)
\curveto(357.109566,206.54526386)(348.769086,203.06265386)(341.887286,200.99999386)
\curveto(335.005496,198.93732386)(327.106976,196.21731386)(324.334996,194.95551386)
\curveto(319.348476,192.68565386)(303.087316,181.82565386)(301.971326,180.01995386)
\curveto(300.867496,178.23392386)(316.778916,154.35917386)(319.537696,153.66196386)
\curveto(321.002216,153.29184386)(325.205866,149.38142386)(328.879146,144.97215386)
\curveto(333.834876,139.02347386)(335.595386,135.87419386)(335.703376,132.76466386)
\curveto(335.912186,126.75139386)(338.639326,122.16044386)(341.469036,123.05855386)
\curveto(343.745636,123.78111386)(344.262686,122.75610386)(343.828726,118.38065386)
\curveto(343.713726,117.22105386)(345.383086,113.84605386)(347.538446,110.88065386)
\curveto(349.693816,107.91525386)(352.285596,103.52026386)(353.297996,101.11401386)
\lineto(355.138726,96.73901386)
\lineto(362.049976,103.92651386)
\curveto(365.851166,107.87964386)(369.194936,111.11401386)(369.480586,111.11401386)
\curveto(369.766236,111.11401386)(369.999946,108.58276386)(369.999946,105.48901386)
\curveto(369.999946,100.06347386)(370.133876,99.86401386)(373.776746,99.86401386)
\curveto(376.705666,99.86401386)(377.884976,99.09230386)(379.029846,96.42651386)
\curveto(379.841816,94.53589386)(380.582436,92.84571386)(380.675676,92.67056386)
\curveto(380.901236,92.24681386)(418.948246,97.67191386)(453.124946,103.00107386)
\curveto(488.272976,108.48169386)(517.346566,113.82322386)(534.986046,118.04101386)
\curveto(542.644336,119.87217386)(549.109686,121.17095386)(549.353476,120.92715386)
\curveto(551.245576,119.03505386)(551.126776,113.75416386)(549.139366,111.40956386)
\curveto(546.694276,108.52502386)(536.446096,106.35564386)(415.105486,83.03646386)
\curveto(384.569786,77.16812386)(359.304166,72.08490386)(358.959666,71.74039386)
\curveto(358.615146,71.39589386)(358.567666,70.88709386)(358.854166,70.60975386)
\curveto(359.140626,70.33240386)(409.437496,78.20176386)(470.624996,88.09722386)
\curveto(531.812496,97.99267386)(582.986136,106.23522386)(584.344186,106.41399386)
\curveto(587.534696,106.83396386)(588.458226,102.82266386)(585.383586,101.89935386)
\curveto(584.141366,101.52630386)(535.593746,92.45162386)(477.499996,81.73339386)
\curveto(331.467176,54.79047386)(135.103076,17.86322386)(85.664366,8.04674386)
\curveto(49.560746,0.87805386)(42.822351,-0.11787614)(31.28937,0.01014386)
\curveto(24.048966,0.09054386)(15.133119,0.65396386)(11.476375,1.26225386)
\closepath
\moveto(282.118186,232.05148386)
\curveto(293.185046,238.90307386)(296.654726,242.00631386)(295.784386,244.27437386)
\curveto(294.912946,246.54529386)(288.833046,249.23157386)(282.326676,250.22039386)
\lineto(277.778346,250.91163386)
\lineto(277.270016,242.92819386)
\curveto(276.885116,236.88358386)(276.092386,234.23233386)(274.005826,232.01129386)
\curveto(268.108046,225.73339386)(271.943746,225.75239386)(282.118186,232.05159386)
\closepath
\moveto(239.374996,231.67748386)
\curveto(234.938936,233.58152386)(223.055676,235.05831386)(224.600386,233.51359386)
\curveto(225.996866,232.11712386)(234.612926,230.12148386)(239.374996,230.09152386)
\lineto(243.124996,230.06792386)
\lineto(239.374996,231.67749386)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(16.470946,1.22868386)
\curveto(5.938378,2.38817386)(1.25,3.92202386)(1.25,6.20839386)
\curveto(1.25,7.03087386)(7.834114,7.18457386)(20.3125,6.65342386)
\curveto(38.487416,5.87977386)(40.626347,6.05503386)(66.249996,10.41733386)
\curveto(156.935366,25.85609386)(233.719626,42.09427386)(236.461436,46.41329386)
\curveto(239.258626,50.81954386)(236.379736,50.88871386)(220.226526,46.80327386)
\curveto(172.410116,34.70954386)(104.463636,21.85074386)(70.725596,18.51037386)
\curveto(48.274816,16.28753386)(31.25,18.31892386)(31.25,23.22057386)
\curveto(31.25,25.96724386)(37.059175,27.41057386)(47.312486,27.21138386)
\curveto(57.127216,27.02073386)(72.594496,29.30229386)(145.624996,41.71341386)
\curveto(190.141996,49.27882386)(229.201996,56.92681386)(244.751136,61.12242386)
\curveto(252.927366,63.32859386)(255.664786,64.68754386)(258.232166,67.81486386)
\curveto(264.444176,75.38167386)(277.936496,88.61398386)(279.439986,88.61398386)
\curveto(280.275126,88.61398386)(281.297596,89.87961386)(281.712136,91.42648386)
\curveto(283.640796,98.62324386)(282.500546,101.73228386)(272.428726,116.73898386)
\curveto(260.060236,135.16762386)(257.454236,140.04396386)(258.282166,143.20997386)
\curveto(258.703446,144.82098386)(256.490076,149.54074386)(251.893976,156.83203386)
\curveto(242.864816,171.15598386)(235.121516,186.75973386)(234.206596,192.47439386)
\curveto(233.565696,196.47747386)(234.002626,197.44487386)(238.269546,201.47048386)
\curveto(241.804316,204.80532386)(242.571546,206.14838386)(241.212816,206.62270386)
\curveto(240.202016,206.97557386)(234.031246,209.25143386)(227.499996,211.68019386)
\curveto(220.968746,214.10895386)(214.498176,216.10014386)(213.120936,216.10505386)
\curveto(211.743716,216.11005386)(209.043126,217.78138386)(207.119646,219.81930386)
\curveto(204.953846,222.11397386)(201.862116,223.79647386)(198.998716,224.23865386)
\curveto(178.931126,227.33760386)(171.181646,230.36680386)(167.382526,236.59712386)
\curveto(163.309876,243.27599386)(165.027566,251.67498386)(171.543096,256.94110386)
\curveto(173.106776,258.20494386)(175.067636,260.77034386)(175.900566,262.64199386)
\curveto(178.181266,267.76693386)(182.192676,268.09499386)(191.419826,263.91120386)
\curveto(196.562116,261.57958386)(202.636146,259.97798386)(208.350726,259.44685386)
\curveto(213.252136,258.99132386)(220.690846,257.55155386)(224.881196,256.24737386)
\curveto(234.074266,253.38617386)(234.642126,254.53602386)(228.202446,262.97244386)
\curveto(225.512466,266.49652386)(223.592286,270.68714386)(223.069196,274.17537386)
\curveto(222.267166,279.52372386)(222.087946,279.71907386)(218.619846,279.02545386)
\curveto(216.462816,278.59404386)(214.207526,278.96555386)(213.024816,279.94713386)
\curveto(211.312366,281.36833386)(210.232326,280.67158386)(205.068086,274.81417386)
\lineto(199.092746,268.03678386)
\lineto(193.828716,273.63788386)
\curveto(190.933486,276.71848386)(188.060666,279.10396386)(187.444646,278.93892386)
\curveto(186.828646,278.77389386)(185.735096,279.74044386)(185.014536,281.08682386)
\curveto(183.931666,283.11019386)(183.148176,283.32329386)(180.497326,282.31543386)
\curveto(176.698786,280.87123386)(174.999996,281.65046386)(174.999996,284.83702386)
\curveto(174.999996,286.11604386)(172.107896,290.32693386)(168.573116,294.19456386)
\lineto(162.146226,301.22659386)
\lineto(162.406146,312.03417386)
\curveto(162.691726,323.90843386)(164.558446,329.81699386)(169.753816,335.29096386)
\curveto(174.922726,340.73707386)(181.862576,343.70599386)(191.266836,344.49442386)
\curveto(201.045766,345.31424386)(207.611816,343.33801386)(215.239196,337.27924386)
\curveto(220.780326,332.87769386)(221.023086,332.84902386)(222.461046,336.42648386)
\curveto(223.468446,338.93277386)(223.600166,338.77067386)(223.670766,334.93757386)
\curveto(223.746366,330.83447386)(223.839786,330.74802386)(225.697446,333.06257386)
\curveto(227.551386,335.37248386)(227.622716,335.30016386)(227.182966,331.55608386)
\curveto(226.831976,328.56786386)(227.144566,327.78572386)(228.484286,328.29982386)
\curveto(229.969976,328.86993386)(229.989546,328.56332386)(228.608536,326.35206386)
\curveto(226.076996,322.29843386)(227.977666,321.91523386)(233.162716,325.43391386)
\curveto(245.149176,333.56813386)(266.779626,335.93380386)(285.467226,331.15432386)
\curveto(314.292976,323.78193386)(356.868816,294.72307386)(375.624946,269.61986386)
\lineto(378.124946,266.27386386)
\lineto(445.624946,273.02838386)
\curveto(509.987386,279.46893386)(524.962536,280.65989386)(523.526466,279.22382386)
\curveto(522.659266,278.35658386)(387.243586,263.61398386)(380.144936,263.61398386)
\curveto(379.506446,263.61398386)(379.278236,262.48898386)(379.637816,261.11398386)
\curveto(380.065526,259.47839386)(381.342836,258.61398386)(383.331946,258.61398386)
\curveto(385.004166,258.61398386)(414.779276,261.42648386)(449.498886,264.86398386)
\curveto(484.218486,268.30148386)(513.581586,271.09688386)(514.750226,271.07597386)
\curveto(528.130346,270.83661386)(454.201586,261.87693386)(395.624996,256.63878386)
\curveto(382.229016,255.44087386)(382.914936,255.96829386)(382.225716,246.33549386)
\curveto(381.508776,236.31541386)(376.473486,225.66354386)(367.997186,216.23586386)
\curveto(361.312976,208.80139386)(353.633516,204.65846386)(338.845786,200.50918386)
\curveto(332.367226,198.69136386)(325.457536,196.37198386)(323.490936,195.35502386)
\curveto(317.393776,192.20206386)(301.249996,180.89887386)(301.249996,179.78286386)
\curveto(301.249996,179.20048386)(303.003376,175.74612386)(305.146396,172.10649386)
\curveto(312.915196,158.91226386)(317.854466,152.23253386)(319.402726,152.82666386)
\curveto(320.264836,153.15748386)(324.233386,149.73430386)(328.221716,145.21960386)
\curveto(334.492116,138.12165386)(335.504226,136.27488386)(335.702486,131.56982386)
\curveto(335.958716,125.48909386)(337.893886,122.36398386)(341.403046,122.36398386)
\curveto(343.128726,122.36398386)(343.751416,121.45402386)(343.755346,118.92648386)
\curveto(343.757346,117.03586386)(345.443386,112.95773386)(347.499996,109.86398386)
\curveto(349.556616,106.77023386)(351.241696,103.62303386)(351.244646,102.87022386)
\curveto(351.246646,102.11739386)(352.361936,100.49516386)(353.720976,99.26524386)
\curveto(356.126226,97.08853386)(356.345446,97.19975386)(361.961816,103.44650386)
\curveto(368.595666,110.82494386)(370.562386,111.52009386)(369.363746,106.06278386)
\curveto(368.319376,101.30778386)(370.485896,98.37457386)(374.329816,99.33933386)
\curveto(376.575766,99.90303386)(377.435326,99.28783386)(378.713436,96.20226386)
\curveto(379.794596,93.59211386)(381.167796,92.36398386)(383.005136,92.36398386)
\curveto(394.245616,92.36398386)(504.826886,110.45869386)(531.410846,116.64801386)
\curveto(540.952896,118.86961386)(549.039026,120.40828386)(549.380026,120.06729386)
\curveto(549.721016,119.72631386)(549.999996,117.55839386)(549.999996,115.24970386)
\curveto(549.999996,111.90984386)(549.354176,110.80655386)(546.839466,109.85047386)
\curveto(543.786626,108.68978386)(447.378896,89.65494386)(387.819876,78.45348386)
\curveto(368.344566,74.79068386)(358.762326,72.47381386)(358.757376,71.42648386)
\curveto(358.753376,70.56711386)(359.349086,69.86398386)(360.081316,69.86398386)
\curveto(361.312986,69.86398386)(405.553686,76.96614386)(535.433586,98.01408386)
\curveto(563.515816,102.56499386)(586.822066,105.95859386)(587.225246,105.55539386)
\curveto(587.628446,105.15221386)(587.404516,104.26849386)(586.727626,103.59161386)
\curveto(586.050736,102.91472386)(533.775736,92.78172386)(470.560966,81.07384386)
\curveto(248.385286,39.92514386)(114.775826,14.68597386)(73.124996,5.99718386)
\curveto(46.301516,0.40153386)(33.654306,-0.66296614)(16.470946,1.22868386)
\closepath
\moveto(282.312426,231.48716386)
\curveto(285.990516,233.68815386)(291.053016,237.31133386)(293.562426,239.53863386)
\lineto(298.124996,243.58829386)
\lineto(295.212476,246.07001386)
\curveto(292.057166,248.75857386)(284.990996,251.09722386)(279.999996,251.10477386)
\curveto(277.076396,251.10977386)(276.864986,250.68018386)(276.719616,244.44812386)
\curveto(276.566696,237.89346386)(274.994416,233.42983386)(271.666086,230.10150386)
\curveto(269.539916,227.97533386)(270.821226,225.68859386)(273.563936,226.71443386)
\curveto(274.697526,227.13842386)(278.634336,229.28614386)(282.312426,231.48715386)
\closepath
\moveto(243.749996,229.66333386)
\curveto(243.749996,231.41394386)(237.796926,233.55724386)(230.578036,234.40568386)
\curveto(226.060516,234.93663386)(223.749996,234.75547386)(223.749996,233.87032386)
\curveto(223.749996,232.25279386)(227.192066,231.08327386)(235.579886,229.85083386)
\curveto(239.042196,229.34211386)(242.296876,228.85569386)(242.812496,228.76993386)
\curveto(243.328126,228.68413386)(243.749996,229.08619386)(243.749996,229.66333386)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(11.43782,2.51777386)
\curveto(7.759872,3.12912386)(3.822372,4.20965386)(2.68782,4.91899386)
\curveto(1.234487,5.82762386)(5.980266,6.05668386)(18.75,5.69427386)
\curveto(34.927512,5.23513386)(39.6955,5.63927386)(63.124996,9.45591386)
\curveto(133.895086,20.98412386)(209.011526,36.10638386)(230.324396,43.11607386)
\curveto(236.570886,45.17052386)(240.350786,49.32817386)(237.104576,50.57386386)
\curveto(236.140296,50.94388386)(229.787916,49.84513386)(222.988176,48.13218386)
\curveto(188.521576,39.44959386)(135.145436,28.42769386)(101.249996,22.99389386)
\curveto(74.524216,18.70946386)(42.801759,17.38548386)(35.9375,20.26799386)
\curveto(33.359375,21.35062386)(31.25,22.81691386)(31.25,23.52638386)
\curveto(31.25,25.29894386)(34.739064,25.86796386)(49.999996,26.58422386)
\curveto(73.990706,27.71019386)(222.720926,53.85656386)(247.106616,61.23501386)
\curveto(255.463096,63.76346386)(256.539066,64.50828386)(262.566036,71.93666386)
\curveto(269.605826,80.61334386)(278.309126,88.61398386)(280.708066,88.61398386)
\curveto(281.537516,88.61398386)(282.592516,91.12380386)(283.052526,94.19138386)
\curveto(283.876996,99.68942386)(282.878446,103.21472386)(279.321336,107.36398386)
\curveto(278.437266,108.39523386)(273.447036,115.92243386)(268.231966,124.09111386)
\curveto(261.330646,134.90102386)(258.749996,140.06773386)(258.749996,143.07496386)
\curveto(258.749996,145.93173386)(256.608426,150.60603386)(251.809866,158.22284386)
\curveto(242.327466,173.27434386)(236.203576,185.93649386)(235.358166,192.23947386)
\curveto(234.722996,196.97498386)(235.072726,197.94501386)(238.802676,201.79332386)
\curveto(241.085966,204.14909386)(242.703826,206.32682386)(242.397916,206.63273386)
\curveto(241.576796,207.45384386)(217.391586,216.24254386)(213.749996,217.04314386)
\curveto(212.031246,217.42101386)(208.820616,219.29726386)(206.615246,221.21258386)
\curveto(203.953026,223.52468386)(200.592396,224.95567386)(196.615246,225.47071386)
\curveto(183.734746,227.13869386)(181.690796,227.62113386)(176.325466,230.25977386)
\curveto(169.434076,233.64889386)(165.717426,238.55478386)(165.873366,244.05627386)
\curveto(166.022576,249.32012386)(169.520516,256.22264386)(172.423536,256.98179386)
\curveto(173.638666,257.29957386)(175.418596,259.34367386)(176.378936,261.52427386)
\curveto(178.680086,266.74941386)(182.856236,267.18168386)(192.163786,263.15814386)
\curveto(196.129946,261.44362386)(204.043816,259.40364386)(209.750146,258.62486386)
\curveto(215.456486,257.84607386)(222.417826,256.40002386)(225.219816,255.41143386)
\curveto(228.021786,254.42283386)(230.806096,253.61398386)(231.407166,253.61398386)
\curveto(233.605976,253.61398386)(232.403626,257.67862386)(228.546476,263.28479386)
\curveto(225.970886,267.02829386)(224.400396,271.03496386)(224.040486,274.78056386)
\lineto(223.488036,280.53007386)
\lineto(218.470196,280.05153386)
\curveto(215.313126,279.75046386)(213.090126,280.15916386)(212.475516,281.15359386)
\curveto(211.775136,282.28684386)(210.313696,281.39657386)(207.311826,278.00799386)
\curveto(205.009076,275.40859386)(202.675176,272.51279386)(202.125386,271.57289386)
\curveto(200.594776,268.95621386)(198.006186,269.53027386)(195.739946,272.98898386)
\curveto(194.613776,274.70773386)(192.861586,276.11398386)(191.846186,276.11398386)
\curveto(190.830786,276.11398386)(189.999996,276.95773386)(189.999996,277.98898386)
\curveto(189.999996,279.02023386)(189.216426,279.86398386)(188.258736,279.86398386)
\curveto(187.301036,279.86398386)(186.183386,280.73459386)(185.775066,281.79868386)
\curveto(185.209376,283.27284386)(183.987296,283.53728386)(180.641326,282.90957386)
\curveto(176.852536,282.19879386)(176.249996,282.41659386)(176.249996,284.49693386)
\curveto(176.249996,285.82308386)(173.236686,290.14593386)(169.553746,294.10328386)
\curveto(162.989096,301.15706386)(162.853146,301.45669386)(162.635966,309.35124386)
\curveto(162.019366,331.76402386)(172.603926,343.57352386)(193.333866,343.60177386)
\curveto(203.392586,343.61557386)(211.713246,340.76437386)(216.977396,335.50021386)
\curveto(218.728616,333.74901386)(220.687596,332.64139386)(221.330716,333.03886386)
\curveto(221.973826,333.43633386)(222.499996,332.88458386)(222.499996,331.81276386)
\curveto(222.499996,329.34279386)(223.703446,329.32242386)(225.487196,331.76216386)
\curveto(226.570586,333.24397386)(226.823386,332.42140386)(226.639716,328.01216386)
\curveto(226.510296,324.90566386)(226.940686,322.36397386)(227.596136,322.36397386)
\curveto(228.251596,322.36397386)(231.807246,324.06801386)(235.497596,326.15071386)
\curveto(255.524726,337.45331386)(282.770736,335.16826386)(312.499996,319.69272386)
\curveto(334.275366,308.35759386)(361.074816,287.46160386)(370.951736,274.11691386)
\curveto(374.901126,268.78091386)(377.734176,266.11400386)(379.453246,266.11398386)
\curveto(380.871286,266.11398386)(413.159996,269.21588386)(451.205936,273.00711386)
\curveto(489.251886,276.79835386)(520.669796,279.61085386)(521.023526,279.25711386)
\curveto(521.377246,278.90338386)(521.032526,278.61397386)(520.257376,278.61397386)
\curveto(519.482266,278.61397386)(506.029136,277.23373386)(490.361546,275.54677386)
\curveto(474.693946,273.85980386)(444.437496,270.75160386)(423.124996,268.63965386)
\curveto(376.514616,264.02081386)(378.355326,264.35297386)(379.459266,260.75983386)
\curveto(379.927486,259.23586386)(380.420226,257.85631386)(380.554246,257.69417386)
\curveto(380.688276,257.53203386)(409.165276,260.21728386)(443.836466,263.66140386)
\curveto(478.507666,267.10551386)(507.718746,269.69405386)(508.749996,269.41370386)
\curveto(509.910446,269.09823386)(509.641236,268.84872386)(508.043576,268.75897386)
\curveto(506.623786,268.67927386)(487.217536,266.69540386)(464.918576,264.35046386)
\curveto(442.619616,262.00553386)(414.742186,259.11207386)(402.968746,257.92056386)
\lineto(381.562496,255.75417386)
\lineto(381.562496,247.89120386)
\curveto(381.562496,237.55097386)(376.616486,226.85262386)(367.067916,216.53902386)
\curveto(359.366496,208.22058386)(353.872896,205.39917386)(333.596046,199.34853386)
\curveto(323.483416,196.33090386)(310.763246,189.15798386)(302.860876,182.01691386)
\lineto(300.096736,179.51907386)
\lineto(303.410016,173.75402386)
\curveto(310.123266,162.07302386)(316.505526,153.45495386)(319.202076,152.42972386)
\curveto(320.725486,151.85051386)(324.738666,148.13813386)(328.120216,144.17997386)
\curveto(332.946686,138.53052386)(334.322116,135.94031386)(334.517866,132.13187386)
\curveto(334.818446,126.28393386)(338.064126,120.89746386)(340.993746,121.38460386)
\curveto(342.567286,121.64623386)(343.040916,120.96817386)(342.803676,118.79347386)
\curveto(342.609576,117.01428386)(344.218186,113.48327386)(346.866176,109.87600386)
\curveto(349.277276,106.59141386)(351.249996,103.08220386)(351.249996,102.07773386)
\curveto(351.249996,101.07327386)(352.318626,99.28435386)(353.624736,98.10233386)
\curveto(355.901946,96.04148386)(356.248416,96.21993386)(362.062236,102.44848386)
\lineto(368.124996,108.94375386)
\lineto(368.749996,104.09136386)
\curveto(369.313966,99.71286386)(369.762246,99.20142386)(373.340296,98.85452386)
\curveto(376.444226,98.55358386)(377.584126,97.67110386)(378.587776,94.79202386)
\curveto(379.292976,92.76910386)(380.095476,91.11397386)(380.371126,91.11397386)
\curveto(380.646776,91.11397386)(396.566646,93.36996386)(415.748646,96.12727386)
\curveto(471.494226,104.14042386)(514.941986,111.74877386)(538.004486,117.53607386)
\curveto(547.991576,120.04223386)(549.918886,119.70096386)(549.980866,115.41538386)
\curveto(550.055266,110.27175386)(546.220326,109.39308386)(408.124996,82.91340386)
\curveto(380.624996,77.64028386)(357.914886,73.13375386)(357.658076,72.89886386)
\curveto(357.401276,72.66397386)(357.529536,71.58996386)(357.943126,70.51217386)
\curveto(358.435796,69.22831386)(359.674416,68.77131386)(361.535046,69.18693386)
\curveto(363.097026,69.53583386)(413.312496,77.69920386)(473.124996,87.32773386)
\curveto(532.937496,96.95627386)(582.891496,105.07786386)(584.133876,105.37571386)
\curveto(585.478316,105.69802386)(586.196776,105.32461386)(585.908636,104.45311386)
\curveto(585.620636,103.58212386)(561.411316,98.54316386)(526.149746,92.01483386)
\curveto(291.278696,48.53075386)(139.267246,19.95665386)(78.849686,7.93432386)
\curveto(49.402156,2.07463386)(42.711644,1.13456386)(31.34969,1.26010386)
\curveto(24.07611,1.34050386)(15.115769,1.90642386)(11.43782,2.51776386)
\closepath
\end{pspicture}
```